# Data written with correct timestamp does not get visualized in Chronograf InfluxDB

Tags: arduino, influxdb, epoch, chronograf

I have an embedded board which sends information from IMU sensors along with a timestamp received from a RTC Module.

The Timestamps are obtained from [Adafruit's RTClib](https://github/adafruit/RTClib)

The code has a function called `unixtime()` which provides me timestamps as follows:

```
1537466106 
1537466107
1537466109
```

If I enter the above mentioned timestamps in [Online Epoch Converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/), it provides me the correct time as of today.

I send this information via HTTP and the information gets stored in InfluxDB under `imu` measurement as follows:

**Query**: `SELECT * FROM imu LIMIT 100`

```
time       eul_x  eul_y  eul_z  liac_x liac_y liac_z location nodeid status
----       -----  -----  -----  ------ ------ ------ -------- ------ ------
1537466106 273.25 -0.88  4.06   -0.06  -0.74  9.81   front    node1  0
1537466107 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.09  -0.87  9.72   front    node1  0
1537466109 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.09  -0.86  9.62   front    node1  0
1537466110 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.07  -0.84  9.67   front    node1  0
1537466111 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.1   -0.85  9.71   front    node1  0
1537466112 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.08  -0.86  9.74   front    node1  0
1537466113 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.04  -0.83  9.7    front    node1  0
1537466114 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.07  -0.84  9.7    front    node1  0
1537466115 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.07  -0.85  9.67   front    node1  0
1537466116 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.06  -0.85  9.67   front    node1  0
1537466117 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.06  -0.84  9.66   front    node1  0
1537466118 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.07  -0.83  9.66   front    node1  0
1537466119 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.09  -0.83  9.68   front    node1  0
1537466120 273.25 -0.88  4.12   -0.08  -0.84  9.7    front    node1  0
1537466121 273.25 -0.81  4.12   -0.08  -0.87  9.52   front    node1  0
1537466123 272.12 -0.81  -3.06  -0.15  0.54   9.74   front    node1  0
```

Now I run an Chronograf Instance on the machine to visualize the data obtained in the above mentioned measurement

**Chronograf Query**

[image: Chronograf Query]

Strangely the table always keeps showing that the timestamps are point to the Epoch of 1970

[image: Table shows wrong timestamps]

Querying a single field from the Database provides the following output:

[image: Query is correct but no result]

#### Research

I read the documents for InfluxDB and they have timestamps for `nanoseconds` precision.

On the contrary the timestamps I mentioned above are in fact, correct but why can Chronograf/ InfluxDB not grasp it correctly?

#### case

I obtain the timestamps as `uint32_t` from the `RTClib` but I am not sure how do I convert it to nanoseconds precision.

I am sending the timestamp information as a string, is it wise to concat zeros to the string? If So how many zeroes might be required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hardware

I am using the **DS3231** RTC module which provides a *precision* of **seconds**. <sup>[1]</sup>.

According to documentation for InfluxDB's HTTP Write Syntax <sup>[2]</sup>:

> All timestamps are assumed to be Unix nanoseconds unless otherwise specified

Since Information provided by the RTC is hardware specific, I assume the precision cannot be changed. (doubtful)

### Solution

I used the `precision` parameter in the HTTP write syntax in my Arduino Sketch as follows:

```
HTTPClient http;
       
       http.begin("http://" + _host + ":" + _port + "/write?db=" + _db + "&precision=s");
       http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

       int httpResponseCode = http.POST(mes_dat);
```

The `precision` value is `s` (in seconds). This will save the information in InfluxDB in the correct way viz.

```
name: imu
time                eul_x  eul_y eul_z liac_x liac_y liac_z location nodeid status
----                -----  ----- ----- ------ ------ ------ -------- ------ ------
1537470381000000000 359.31 0     9.81  -0.05  -1.47  9.82   front    node1  0
1537470382000000000 359.37 0     10.81 -0.05  -1.72  9.75   front    node1  0
1537470383000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.81 -0.06  -1.75  9.71   front    node1  0
1537470384000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.81 -0.03  -1.75  9.67   front    node1  0
1537470385000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.81 -0.05  -1.76  9.73   front    node1  0
1537470386000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.75 -0.05  -1.76  9.72   front    node1  0
1537470387000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.75 -0.06  -1.77  9.64   front    node1  0
1537470388000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.75 -0.02  -1.76  9.61   front    node1  0
1537470389000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.75 -0.04  -1.76  9.61   front    node1  0
1537470390000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.75 -0.03  -1.82  9.61   front    node1  0
1537470391000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.63 -0.03  -1.78  9.72   front    node1  0
1537470393000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.63 -0.05  -1.78  9.63   front    node1  0
1537470394000000000 359.37 -0.06 10.63 -0.05  -1.76  9.76   front    node1  0
```

And Visualization is perfect in Chronograf with all the above mentioned Queries in the question.

[[1] Adafruit's DS3231](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ds3231-precision-rtc-breakout/arduino-usage#reading-the-time-4-17)

[[2] InfluxDB HTTP Write Documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/write_protocols/write_syntax/#http)